# How to generate individual sorted pagination links in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The pagination documentation has good info on how to add sorting to the paginated links for your data:

```
<?php echo $orders->appends(array('sort' => 'name', 'sort_dir'=>'asc'))->links();
```

to generate links like this:

```
http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=name&sort_dir=asc
```

So now you have a table with headers and values and a series of paginated links you can click.  Let's say I wanted to change the headers to be clickable links that allowed you to sort by that header.  How would I generate that URL?

For example, lets say our current URL is what I said above:

```
http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=name&sort_dir=asc
```

And I wanted to click the "NAME" table header in order to change the sorting direction.  The URL I would want is:

```
http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=name&sort_dir=desc
```

I have a controller called : AdminController.php this is the method used:

```
    public function getAdmins() {

 // CACHE SORTING INPUTS
$allowed = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'activated', 'crated_at'); // add allowable columns to search on
$sort = in_array(Input::get('sort'), $allowed) ? Input::get('sort') : 'first_name'; // if user type in the url a column that doesnt exist app will default to first_name
$order = Input::get('order') === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'; // default desc
$action = null;
// select all admins Group = 1
$admins = DB::table('users')
     ->join('users_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'users_roles.user_id')
     ->where('users_roles.role_id', '=' ,0)
    ->orderBy($sort, $order)
    ->paginate($this->perpage);

// check for actions
if (!is_null(Input::get('action'))) 
    {

            $action = Input::get('action');

            if ($action == "add")
            {
                $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.admins-add');
            }

    }
    else
    {

        // get current counter admin counts
        $counter = $admins->getFrom();
        View::share('counter', $counter);
        View::share('sort', $sort);
        View::share('order', $order);

        // share admin with template
        View::share('admins', $admins);

        $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.admins');
    }
    }
```

1). how could I display the columns headers links in Laravel inside my view page?

Thanks

Comment: use javascript ofcourse.... this has nothing to do with server side.

Comment: I need to generate header links , when you click on first name , it will change sort = first_name and so on

Comment: i got what you are trying to do here.... but this is client side coding. not server side. what did you do in client side to achieve it?

Comment: in the client side I have a table with headers first name last name email etc, I want to make those links , where if you click on first_name it will take you to : http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=first_name&sort_dir=asc and Last Name header will go to : http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=last_name&sort_dir=asc , and for the sort_dir to change if it was asc it will change to desc

Comment: Of course you can do it server side... check the answer

Comment: Where I dont see an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the params:

```
$params = Request::except(['sort','sort_dir']);
$sort_dir = (Request::get('sort_dir') == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
$sort = 'whataverYourColumnIs';

$attributes = array_merge(['sort' => $sort, 'sort_dir' => $sort_dir], $params);

// and for the link for example:
link_to_action('AdminsController@getIndex', 'columnName', $attributes);
```

Comment: whats 'something.index' , in my case what is the link to my route? 'admins'??

Comment: Whatever your route is named like, might be admins.index for example.

Comment: well I have Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');

Comment: and there is a method inside AdminController : getAdmins() , and the URL admin/admins

Comment: I tried 'admin.admins' I got an error undefined route?

Comment: try now, for restful controller it's link_to_action in fact

Comment: well it kinda worked , but the link name is first_name , how can I make it First Name , the database column is 'first_name'

Comment: columnName can be whatever you like, it's just for the link. $sort must be exact column name. I suggest wrapping it as a helper so you don't need to use this whole code everytime you need a sortable column

Comment: You mean create this as a helper class and use it?

Comment: do we put this : link_to_action('AdminsController@getIndex', 'columnName', $attributes); in the view file??

Comment: Yes I am having a problem with that because you have $sort ='first_name'; // so that is static and how about to get it from the URL ?

Comment: and why are you merging the attributes with the para? I dont get that part?

Comment: You don't want to get column name from the URL, but the other way around, right? On every column in your sortable table this will be different. And the values are merged so you have both page=3 and sort=column&sort_dir=asc in your url. In other words you still have all the data (eg. pagination, maybe search query or anything).

Comment: yes but the generated link is not sort=column&sort_dir=asc , it generates link like : admin/admins/first_name/asc , now my code doesnt understand which one is sort and which one is sort_dir

Comment: basically its a clean URL generated

Comment: Then sth wrong, as it should give you query string like this domain.com/admins?sort=column&sort_dir=asc&page=2

Comment: Are you sure its a query string , I am getting with slashes ?

Comment: I am getting this : admin/admins/first_name/desc?page=2 for my pagination link and for the header link I am getting this : admin/admins/first_name/asc/2 , thats strange?